# JavaScript recursive function loops infinitely and didn't get the right answer

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am writing a recursive function to find out the item which has the same id as I pass to the function.

As you can see that each object item has an `id` property and the item also has a `sub_categories` property which is an array contains some other objects or an empty array.

```
const arr = [
    {
        "id": 1013,
        "code": "CAT1",
        "name": {
            "en": "TOP 1",
            "fr": "TOP 1"
        },
        "_name": "TOP 1",
        "level": 1,
        "sub_categories": [
            {
                "id": 1016,
                "code": "SUB1",
                "name": {
                    "en": "Child 1",
                    "fr": "Child 1"
                },
                "_name": "Child 1",
                "level": 2,
                "sub_categories": [
                    {
                        "id": 1017,
                        "code": "SUB11",
                        "name": {
                            "en": "Child 2",
                            "fr": "Child 2"
                        },
                        "_name": "Child 2",
                        "level": 3,
                        "sub_categories": [
                            {
                                "id": 1018,
                                "code": "SUB111",
                                "name": {
                                    "en": "Child 3",
                                    "fr": "Child 3"
                                },
                                "_name": "Child 3",
                                "level": 4,
                                "sub_categories": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 1019,
                                        "code": "SUB21",
                                        "name": {
                                            "en": "Child 4",
                                            "fr": "Child 4"
                                        },
                                        "_name": "Child 4",
                                        "level": 5,
                                        "sub_categories": []
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1014,
        "code": "CAT2",
        "name": {
            "en": "TOP 2",
            "fr": "TOP 2"
        },
        "_name": "TOP 2",
        "level": 1,
        "sub_categories": [
            {
                "id": 1020,
                "code": "SUB22",
                "name": {
                    "en": "Child 1",
                    "fr": "Child 1"
                },
                "_name": "Child 1",
                "level": 2,
                "sub_categories": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1015,
        "code": "CAT3",
        "name": {
            "en": "TOP 3",
            "fr": "TOP 3"
        },
        "_name": "TOP 3",
        "level": 1,
        "sub_categories": []
    }
]
```

```
const arrFilter = (targetId) => {
        let res = null;
        for(let y = 0; y < arr.length; y++) {
          if (arr[y].id === targetId) {
          res = arr[y];
       } else if(arr[y].sub_categories.length) {
          res = arrFilter(arr[y].sub_categories, targetId)
       }
      
       if(res !== null) return res;
    }
}

console.log(arrFilter(1017))
```

When I pass the id `1017`, it throws an error said `Maximum call stack size exceeded`, it seems loops infinitely. Anyone know why my code loops infinitely?

Comment: It's not recursive, as it always iterates global `arr` array, not subarray etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `arr` in your function to search for the item, however, if you call the function for the second time, you're still using `arr`.

You'll need to pass the array itself to the function so the second (recursive) time you only search that part:

```js
const arr = [{"id": 1013, "code": "CAT1", "name": {"en": "TOP 1", "fr": "TOP 1"}, "_name": "TOP 1", "level": 1, "sub_categories": [{"id": 1016, "code": "SUB1", "name": {"en": "Child 1", "fr": "Child 1"}, "_name": "Child 1", "level": 2, "sub_categories": [{"id": 1017, "code": "SUB11", "name": {"en": "Child 2", "fr": "Child 2"}, "_name": "Child 2", "level": 3, "sub_categories": [{"id": 1018, "code": "SUB111", "name": {"en": "Child 3", "fr": "Child 3"}, "_name": "Child 3", "level": 4, "sub_categories": [{"id": 1019, "code": "SUB21", "name": {"en": "Child 4", "fr": "Child 4"}, "_name": "Child 4", "level": 5, "sub_categories": [] } ] } ] } ] } ] }, {"id": 1014, "code": "CAT2", "name": {"en": "TOP 2", "fr": "TOP 2"}, "_name": "TOP 2", "level": 1, "sub_categories": [{"id": 1020, "code": "SUB22", "name": {"en": "Child 1", "fr": "Child 1"}, "_name": "Child 1", "level": 2, "sub_categories": [] } ] }, {"id": 1015, "code": "CAT3", "name": {"en": "TOP 3", "fr": "TOP 3"}, "_name": "TOP 3", "level": 1, "sub_categories": [] } ];

const arrFilter = (search, targetId) => {
        let res = null;
        for (let y = 0; y < search.length; y++) {
          if (search[y].id === targetId) {
          res = search[y];
       } else if(search[y].sub_categories.length) {
          res = arrFilter(search[y].sub_categories, targetId)
       }
      
       if(res !== null) return res;
    }
}

console.log(arrFilter(arr, 1017))
```

---

Slightly improved version could look something like:

```js
const arr = [{"id": 1013, "code": "CAT1", "name": {"en": "TOP 1", "fr": "TOP 1"}, "_name": "TOP 1", "level": 1, "sub_categories": [{"id": 1016, "code": "SUB1", "name": {"en": "Child 1", "fr": "Child 1"}, "_name": "Child 1", "level": 2, "sub_categories": [{"id": 1017, "code": "SUB11", "name": {"en": "Child 2", "fr": "Child 2"}, "_name": "Child 2", "level": 3, "sub_categories": [{"id": 1018, "code": "SUB111", "name": {"en": "Child 3", "fr": "Child 3"}, "_name": "Child 3", "level": 4, "sub_categories": [{"id": 1019, "code": "SUB21", "name": {"en": "Child 4", "fr": "Child 4"}, "_name": "Child 4", "level": 5, "sub_categories": [] } ] } ] } ] } ] }, {"id": 1014, "code": "CAT2", "name": {"en": "TOP 2", "fr": "TOP 2"}, "_name": "TOP 2", "level": 1, "sub_categories": [{"id": 1020, "code": "SUB22", "name": {"en": "Child 1", "fr": "Child 1"}, "_name": "Child 1", "level": 2, "sub_categories": [] } ] }, {"id": 1015, "code": "CAT3", "name": {"en": "TOP 3", "fr": "TOP 3"}, "_name": "TOP 3", "level": 1, "sub_categories": [] } ];

const arrFilter = (search, targetId) => {
    for (const obj of search) {
        if (obj.id === targetId) {
            return obj;
        }
        if (obj.sub_categories.length > 0) {
            const tmp = arrFilter(obj.sub_categories, targetId);
            if (tmp) {
                return tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(arrFilter(arr, 1014))
```